# difference between two list and handle exception if results are null

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns. Each column has list of items and I am trying to subtract one column form another as below.

```
 test['new'] = test['products'].apply(set) - test['old_products'].apply(set)
```

This works.

When there are no elements for newly created column looks like `test['new'] = set()`
How to handle this exception and make as `NA` if the result is null. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data frames and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual with exceptions. Try something like:

```
try:
    test['new'] = test['products'].apply(set) - test['old_products'].apply(set)
except:
    test['new'] = 'NA'
```

Check documentation there: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

**EDIT.** After discussion, it seems that there is no exception, so answer is:

```
if  test['products'].apply(set) - test['old_products'].apply(set) == set():
    test['new'] = 'NA'
else:
    test['new'] = test['products'].apply(set) - test['old_products'].apply(set)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried as above. I still get teh value as `set()` if the list if empty after subtraction. Thanks.

Comment: @Lilly then it seems that you do not have exception, I've updated the answer